# Exception Value: missing 1 required positional argument

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'd like to get the default value using def/function

Take a look on the snippet code:

models.py

```
from django.http import HttpRequest

class Contacts(Model):
    def get_client_ip(ip):
        x_forwarded_for = request.META.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')
        if x_forwarded_for:
           ip = x_forwarded_for.split(',')[0]
        else:
           ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
        return ip

    ipaddress = CharField(default=get_client_ip, max_length=20, verbose_name='your IP Address')
```

makemigrations and migrate executed it without erros or warnings.

When I ran I got the following:
Exception Value: get_client_ip() missing 1 required positional argument: 'ip'

Could you please help me on it?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `def get_client_ip(self, ip):`

Comment: Also your `get_client_ip` does not know about `request`

Comment: @JacquesGaudin, I did what you told me and I got the following: "Exception Value: get_client_ip() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'self' and 'ip' "

Comment: @ilse2005, okay and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple errors in your code.

`Value: get_client_ip() missing 1 required positional argument:`

That is because `default=get_client_ip` calls the function without arguments. Also I don't understand why `get_client_ip` needs the ip? Just remove that and use `@staticmethod`

```
@staticmethod
def get_client_ip():
    x_forwarded_for = request.META.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')
    if x_forwarded_for:
       ip = x_forwarded_for.split(',')[0]
    else:
       ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
    return ip
```

But this will also not work, because `request` is not defined in `get_client_ip`. Request is not visible to Models. The easiest way to fix this is to remove the default and move `get_client_ip` logic to your view and set the `ip` field on model creation.

Comment: could you please explain this: "set the ip field on model creation" ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can pass arguments to the default field. The best way I can think of achieving what you want is to override the save function of the model.

Eg:

```
 class Contacts(models.Model):
     ipaddress = CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name='your IP Address')
     ...
     def save(self):
       if not self.id: #first time saving the model
         self.ip = self.get_client_ip(self.ip)
       super(Contacts, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

**EDIT:**

Sorry just realized that you're parsing HTTP headers to get the field value. You should set this from the controller directly for your model and use the `save` function to perform any cleanups that you might need.

Comment: I did what you told me and I got when I saved it: Exception Value: 'Contacts' object has no attribute 'id'
relate to this line: if not self.id: #first time saving the model.  The model def remain like this:     def get_client_ip(): Could you help me on it?

Comment: By `id` I am referring to the primary field of your model. Have you defined any field as `primary` or a `OneToOneField`? use that instead of `id`